# BigQuery: Why does Table Range Decorators return wrong result sometimes?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been using the Table Range Decorators feature daily since May in order to only query the data from the last 7 days in some of my tables.

Since 2 weeks, I've noticed that sometimes some data is missing when I use that feature. For example, if do a query to get the results for the last 7 days (by adding "@-604800000--1" to table), some data will be missing as opposed to if I query on the whole table (without a table decorator).

I wonder what could explain this and if there is a fix coming soon to address this?

If this can help the BigQuery team, I've noticed that when using Table Decorators some data was missing for us for October 16th between around 16:00 and 20:00 UTC time.

For the BigQuery team here are 2 jobs ids where some data is missing: *job_-xtL4PlIYhNjQ5weMnssvqDmd6U* , *job_9ASNxqq_swjCd1eMmiQ6SmPpxlQ*

and 1 job id where data is correct(without decorators): job_QbcRwYGbQv0BZdHreQEvRlYh-mM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with table decorators containing a time range.  Due to a bug in BigQuery, it is possible for certain time ranges to omit data that should be included within the time range.

We're working on a fix and plan to have it released next week.  After this fix is deployed time range decorators should again work as expected.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I would like to understand when and what this bug affected, so i can fix the derived problems it caused on my side.

Comment: The issue could happen when range decorators are used for a table that was appended to in many small pieces, and so BigQuery had compacted the table representation. If the time range decorator overlapped the compaction period, we'd need to unwind the compaction operation. There was a bug in this, so that some data could be left out. Unfortunately, it is difficult to tell when this occurred. We do have a fix and should hopefully release it soon.

Comment: Guys, can you please update regarding fix timelines? This is a major bug over 2 weeks now. This bug causes my BI system to present wrong data, so my users lose confidence in the BQ based solution. And it costs quit a bit as I need to manually run everything again after it ran automatically on partial data. (The way this bug is being handled causes BQ to lose points... I was asked if we should seek alternative analytics Infra)

Comment: This bug should now be fixed in production.  The flaw was in some code that interpreted timestamps on internally created files.  Since the files themselves are correct, the fix should be immediate and cover all existing data.

Comment: Still getting partial results. re opened a bug (181)

Comment: I'm still having this problem